# Samba 4 Database File sam.ldb Missing?

Tags: server, 20.04, samba, user-management, samba4

I am on Ubuntu Server 20.04, running Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu. I need to modify a Samba user account, but I am unable to open `sam.ldb` due to it apparently not being present. Here is the output:

```
$ samba-tool user edit username
ltdb: tdb(/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb: No such file or directory

Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb': No such file or directory
Failed to connect to 'tdb:///var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb' with backend 'tdb': Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb': No such file or directory
ERROR(ldb): uncaught exception - Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb': No such file or directory
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 186, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/user.py", line 2435, in run
    samdb = SamDB(url=H, session_info=system_session(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/samdb.py", line 65, in __init__
    super(SamDB, self).__init__(url=url, lp=lp, modules_dir=modules_dir,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/__init__.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.connect(url, flags, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/samdb.py", line 81, in connect
    super(SamDB, self).connect(url=url, flags=flags,
```

I cannot `list` users either. I haven't tried any other subcommands yet.

I checked the folder it's referring to. Here are the contents:

```
$ ls
msg.sock  netlogon_creds_cli.tdb  passdb.tdb  secrets.ldb  secrets.tdb
```

The Samba server is running only as a File Server. I'm not running an LDAP (as far as I know). I installed Samba originally under Ubuntu Server 18.04. Other than adding shares to the .conf file I've never made any modifications to the installation.

Comment: I am going to make a big guess here, you are running Samba as a standalone server and you are trying to use the tools meant for a Samba AD DC. can you post your smb.conf file (please remove any lines that start with '#' or ';')

Comment: My Samba install is configured as a [File Server](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-file-server). No AD is needed since there is no Windows network. [Samba defines](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/samba-tool.8.html) `samba-tool` as its "Main Samba administration tool." Would that not mean it should function regardless? If it is only for AD DC setups, should there not be a message informing the user?

Comment: Good point, the man page should say something like 'Main Samba AD administration tool'. You need to use the old smbpasswd & pdbedit tools with a Samba standalone server, 'samba-tool' is only for AD domain computers, users & groups etc.